# Why do I get a kernel panic if booting into Ubuntu after having used Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, kernel

A friend of mine has a dual-boot system with Ubuntu and Windows 7. He encounters a kernel panic if he wants to boot up Ubuntu after a Windows session.

This sounds pretty strange to me, however I actually witnessed the behavior.

Has anybody of you heard about this before? Any idea what the reason might be?

Comment: You should be more discrete. So, if he starts up the computer to windows or ubuntu it works fine.. but if he restarts windows and chooses ubuntu at grub it fails? is that correct?

Comment: If a hard reboot (pushing power button) works fine and a warm reboot (reboot from Windows) fails, it's probably a BIOS problem. Try seeing if there's a BIOS update available on your computer manufacturer's website.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on an old ami bios.  Disabling the 'plug and play os' feature in the bios worked for me.  A friend also recommends disabling quick boot, but the last time I saw that was long ago. I remembering it even going so far as when it shifted to gui mode, the windows desktop would flicker for a second.